# How to add static, non overlapping, not vanishing headers to multicolum listviews?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a listview with multiple columns. Now I want to add headers on top of each column with some text in it. These fields should be there all the time, even if I scroll down the listview, and they shall not overlap with the content in the listview.

I tried to follow the example [given here](http://geodatadesign.blogspot.ch/2012/05/android-static-multi-line-listview.html), but only 'header1' is shown which overlaps with the listview data. 'header2' is not shown at all! So how to do it right?

I especially do not understand my problem as I used `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` both in the header-LinearLayout and in the ListView...

Here is the current definition of my layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/header_line1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#f00"
            android:text="header1"
            />
        <!-- Second header line -->
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/header_line2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#0f0"
            android:text="header2"
            />
    </LinearLayout>


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" 
    >
    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And here is the definition of the listview:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/listname"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.30"
        android:text="">
    </TextView>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/listok"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.1"
        android:text="">
    </TextView>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/listnok"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.1"
        android:text="">
    </TextView>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/listhist"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.2"
        android:text="">
    </TextView>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/listprandom"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.15"
        android:text="">
    </TextView>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/listphist"
        android:layout_width="0px"
        android:layout_height="100px"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0px"
        android:layout_marginRight="0px"
        android:layout_marginTop="0px"
        android:layout_weight="0.075">
    </TextView>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/listptot"
        android:layout_width="0px"
        android:layout_height="100px"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0px"
        android:layout_marginRight="0px"
        android:layout_marginTop="0px"
        android:layout_weight="0.075">
    </TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: If you want your headers to align with the list item columns, then the header `LinearLayout` should be pretty much an exact copy of the list item `LinearLayout`. As for the overlap, look at the `ListView`s attributes. You have it aligned to the top of its parent, which is also where the header layout is currently. Add an ID to the header `LinearLayout`, and `layout_below` with that ID to the `ListView`.

Comment: It worked!!! Thanks so much!!